# C converting 2D Array to double pointer prints unexpected value

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

The following program is printing 9 instead of 17 why?

```
int main()
{
   int **ptr;
   int i=0, j=0;
   int arr[2][2]={{17,9},{7,19}};

   ptr=(int**)arr;
   printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Dinesh why are you printing ptr[0]? Are you meaning to print ptr[0][0]?

Comment: Do you mean `int *ptr` ?

Comment: This is wrong, a 2D array is not compatible with a pointer-to-pointer. Hint: why did you get a warning when assigning `ptr` to `arr`? (Because you did, that's why you included a cast.)

Comment: `ptr[0]` type is `int*`. try "%p"

Comment: I got this output using gcc on solaris but when I tried the same code in gcc on Linux, MinGW and Visual Studio I got the expected 17 why?

Comment: even replacing %d with %x or %p gives the same output but in different format.

Comment: I think that all binary compiled with GCC above version 3.4.3 will give 17 as output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array of arrays is **not** the same as a pointer to a pointer.

Reason being that the memory layout is completely different.

For an array of arrays:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | arr[1][0] | arr[1][1] |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

For a pointer to pointer:

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| arr[0] | arr[1] | ... |
+--------+--------+-----+
  |        |
  |        V
  |      +-----------+-----------+-----+
  |      | arr[1][0] | arr[1][1] | ... |
  |      +-----------+-----------+-----+
  V
+-----------+-----------+-----+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

---

As arrays decays to pointer, you can have a pointer to arrays though:

```
int (*ptr)[2] = arr;
```

Comment: Wow! Nice to see at 100k+ :). Congo!

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this behavior is your program invokes **undefined behavior**. You are using `%d` specifier to print a pointer type. Using a wrong format specifier invokes UB.
And note that, a pointer to pointer type object is not a 2D array. *Arrays are not pointers*, although array names decays to pointer to its first element.

Comment: Exactly. Not to mention that a 2D array is not a double pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to pointer is certainly meaningless when assigned with 2 dimensional array. Use pointer to an array as below which is useful in accessing array of arrays.

```
int main()
{
   int (*ptr)[2]; // ptr is pointer to array of 2 ints
   int arr[2][2]={{17,9},{7,19}};
   ptr = arr;
   printf("%d\n", (*ptr)[0]);
   return 0;
}
```