# Memory allocation for a 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c++ and trying to understand how memory allocating is done for 2D arrays.I have gone through several threads in SOF and these answers.

[answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813864/4384418)

[answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203856/4384418)

Those answers says that continuous memory allocation happen for 2D arrays as well like for normal arrays. (correct me if I'm wrong) Answer 2 mention that it should be able to access `array[i][j]` th element using`*(array + (i * ROW_SIZE) + j)`

But when I'm trying to do that it gives me an unexpected result.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    cout<<*((array+1*2) + 1)<<endl;  
    cout<<**((array+1*2) + 1)<<endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0x76e1f4799008
2012576581
```

It doesn't give me `array[i][j]` th element. Can some one explain what is happening here, whether that solution is wrong or have i misunderstood the previous answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to get a pointer to the first element of the *whole thing*, i.e. not just to the first row:

```
int *p = &array[0][0]
```

After that, you can index `p` like you want:

```
std::cout << *(p + 1*2 + 1) << std::endl;
```

---

The reason why your initial tries didn't work is related to types. What is happening is that in your first try you are trying to evaluate

```
*(array + 1*2 + 1)
```

Now since, `array` is of type "array-of-length-2" containing "array-of-length-2" containing `int`s, i.e. `(int[2])[2]` what this will do is increment `array` with 3 times the size of its elements, which in turn are `int[2]`. *This will jump outside of your array.* In fact `*(array+3)` is equivalent to `array[3]`. Now, that clearly is something with type `int[2]`, which will decay to a pointer when you try to print it. In your second try, you dereference this, yielding something like `array[3][0]`, which now is of the right type, but again, points outside of the array.

Answer (score 3):

it is more like when you simulate a 2d array as a one dimensional array like this

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

and the array will be 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  to access 4 it should be *(a[0]+(1*3)+1)a[0] is the same as a(name of array).

Answer (score 1):

array is 2D pointer

```
**array = array[0][0]
*(*array + j) = array[0][j]
*(*(array+i) + j) = array[i][j]
```

Comment: yeah.. that is right but that solution is not equal with `(array + (i * ROW_SIZE) + j)`. I want to know whether  `(array + (i * ROW_SIZE) + j)` is wrong or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This answer says that `An array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to a pointer.` http://stackoverflow.com/a/21580967/4384418